# What is the best way to parse a string into a null terminated array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am writing a simple command line interpreter. My code reads a string using scanf and parses it using the function getArgs() shown below, and then uses that array as an argument to execvp to perform a command such as ls. It works if I call only 'ls' but when I call 'ls -la', it gives the same result as 'ls'.

```
void getArgs(char* command, char* args[]){

    int i = 0;
    char* p = strtok(command, " "); 
    args[i] = p;

    while(p != NULL){
        i++; 
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        args[i] = p;
}
}
```

Here is my main function which includes the initialization of the arguments given:

```
int main(){
char *args[1024];
char example[30]; 
char exit[5] = {'q', 'u', 'i', 't', '\0'};
int f1; 
int status;
size_t n = sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0]);

while(strncmp(example, exit, 30) !=0){

    printf(">>>");
    scanf("%s", example);
    getArgs(example, args);
    int x = strncmp(args[0], exit, 30);

    if (x != 0){
        f1 = fork(); 
        if (f1 != 0){
            /* wait  for child process to terminate */
            waitpid(f1, &status, 0);
        }
        else{myExec(args);}}         
    else{
        return 0;}}
    return 0; 
}
```

My guess as to the problem is that my argument array, args, is not null terminated and so when I attempt to use it in myExec():

```
void myExec(char* args[]){
    execvp(args[0], args);
}
```

this does not work. So my question is, can I set the item after the last non-empty part of my array to null to try to get this to work? If so, how can I do that? Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: I added the rest of the code, also args[i] = strdup(p); gives 'Segmentation error: 11'.

Comment: char exit[] = "quit";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-la` is being ignored because `scanf("%s", example);` will stop at the first space. I suggest

```
scanf(" %29[^\n]", example);
```

Which will

- Ignore whitespace left in the buffer from the previous command.
- Restrict the string input from overflowing.
- Allow space seperators in the command.

Note too that in the first execution of `while(strncmp(example, exit, 30) !=0)` the `example` is an uninitialised variable, so that needs to be

```
char example[30] = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` directive stops scanning at the first whitespace character, so it won't properly capture any commands with spaces (such as `ls -la`).  You should use `fgets` to get user input if you want to preserve any whitespace:

```
if ( fgets( example, sizeof example, stdin ) )
{
  getArgs( example, args);
  ...
}
```

`fgets` will read up to `sizeof example - 1` characters into `example` (including the newline!) and 0-terminate the string.  You may want to take that newline into account with your `strtok` call.